# Is there any way that I can tag my react app docker images with a version?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

I need to tag every react app docker images I build with their specific version numbers. Is there any way that I can do that? Maybe using semantic versioning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As referred in [Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_tag/), you can do in this way:

```
docker tag SOURCE_IMAGE[:TAG] TARGET_IMAGE[:TAG]
```

Example:

```
docker tag my_react_image my_react_image:v1
docker tag my_react_image2 my_react_image:v2
```